# Error when declaring a __block variable, "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

Here's a simple program using `__block` variables:

```
typedef void (^incrementBlock)(void);

__block int incrementMe = 0;

incrementBlock add_one = ^{
   incrementMe++;
};

incrementBlock add_two = ^{
   incrementMe++;
   incrementMe++;
};

add_one();
add_two();

printf("%d", incrementMe);
```

When I compile this, I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "___objc_personality_v0",
>   referenced from:
>         _main in test-b0a9a6.o
>         Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in test-b0a9a6.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It definitely is a problem with declaring `incrementMe`as a  `__block int`, when I comment it out it works.
I tried compiling with gcc and it also didn't work.

I got this example more or less straight from a book so it should work.

Is my declaration deprecated?  Should I be declaring a mutable block variable differently?

Comment: Isn't `__block` an Objective-C keyword? Why is this question tagged C++?

Comment: Could https://twitter.com/tewha/status/271806872187703296 be the case?

Comment: @RSahu
Sorry I am just learning about blocks so I wasn't sure how to tag-- my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to make sure to link with the Objective-C runtime library.  Add `-lobjc` to your linker command line and you should be good.